# Exclude android Instrumentation tests while generating Jacoco report

Tags: android, gradle, jacoco, android-instrumentation

I have multiple modules in Android application. I need to automate code coverage report in the CI/CD pipeline where it doesn’t have physical/virtual android device and not possible to attach a device.

Integrated Jacoco from - https://github.com/gouline/android-samples/blob/master/jacoco/jacoco.gradle

When I try to generate coverage report via gradle command

```
>> ./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport
```

It fails with the below error log

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: No connected devices!
```

So I tried to exclude the gradle tasks (connectdDebugAndroidTest) via command

```
>> ./gradlew createDebugCoverageReport -x app:connectedDebugAndroidTest -x module1:connectedDebugAndroidTest
```

Getting error as below -

```
> Task :module1:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':vpn:createDebugAndroidTestCoverageReport'.
> java.io.IOException: No coverage data to process in directories [/Users/abc/ws/prjName/module1/build/outputs/code_coverage/debugAndroidTest/connected]
```

I have instrumentation tests in the module1

How to exclude Instrumentation tests while generating Jacoco report when the device is not connected.

*update*:

I am able to generate Jacoco reports individually for each module via

```
./gradlew testDebugUnitTestCoverage
```

But I am looking for a integrated report. How to integrate multiple jacoco reports from modules into one report?

Comment: Did you get any solution on this?

Comment: No; generating individual module reports.

Answer (score 0):

Plz remove **createDebugCoverageReport** from **jacocoTestReport** task

```
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport,
        dependsOn: ['testDebugUnitTest']) {
    group = "Reporting"
    description = "Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests."

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    def fileFilter = ['androidx/**/*.*',
                      '**/view/*.*',
                      '**/data/*.*',
                      '**/data/model/*.*',
                      '**/generated/callback/*.*',
                      '**/lambda$*.class',
                      '**/lambda.class',
                      '**/*lambda.class',
                      '**/*lambda*.class']

    def debugTree = fileTree(dir:
            "${buildDir}/intermediates/javac/debug/classes",
            excludes: fileFilter
    )

    def mainSrc = "/src/main/java"

    sourceDirectories.from = files([mainSrc])

    classDirectories.from = files([debugTree])
    executionData.from = fileTree(dir: "${buildDir}", includes:[
            "/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec"])
}
```